# Drupal rendered page for directory root, followed by static pages?

Tags: uri, .htaccess

I have a directory that I want to load through the Drupal system, which of course is fine with clean URLS:

> /my-dynamic-page/

However at this directory I then want to serve static pages

> /my-dynamic-page/static1

When I add a folder for /my-dynamic-page/ to the server, this now bypasses the Drupal system. While the static pages now work, when you try and load /my-dynamic-page you get a Forbidden error. This is because the Drupal system has been bypassed (there is a physical folder now) so the system looks for an index file.

How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your own .htaccess file under the my-dynamic-page and my-dynamic-page/static1 with only this in it:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm
```

Comment: Hey J, this doesn't seem to be working for me. The problem is the folder /my-dynamic-page/ doesn't have an index file, because the folder just serves for the inner static files. When the /my-dynamic-page is loaded I somehow need to tell it to use the root index.php I think?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to J.Reynolds whose answer pointed me in the right direction to use DirectoryIndex.

In the dynamic directory I created a .htaccess with the following:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /index.php
```

So it looks for a local index.php first, if not then goes to the root PHP index file.